# How can I control ringer volume?

Tags: iphone, ios

I needed an app that would control the ringer volume of an iPhone. According to a developer I have been talking to, this is all good and possible on an Android phone but not on iOS. I just wanted to confirm if this is the case that it is not possible in iOS?

If not, then is there a way around controlling the ringer settings? I'm not into developing iOS apps yet so I personally have no clue.

Comment: Why do you want to use an app for that? Do you have requirements which are not covered by the volume up/down buttons?

Comment: Why would anyone want this? Even if it was user-controllable, if I turn my phone down because I'm in a quieter location, then one app suddenly blurts out at full tilt, that app would be in the bin shortly afterwards. [& vice versa, quiet app, loud physical volume... I'd miss the notification]

Comment: I need an app so the ringer can be controlled automatically if certain variables are met. For example when I connect to a specific wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Assistive Touch, which can be enabled in Settings > General > Accessibility to trigger Hardware Buttons.

If you're asking from a developer perspective you should ask in Stack Overflow.